# Good Crosswords

Tags: crosswords

I'm looking for a good online crossword that I can do when I have breaks in my day. Since I'm a web designer, I want something that has a well designed website. Also, since I like to think I'm smart, I want something large though not necessarily complex.

The best I could find is the Times Crossword (nytimes.com/crosswords/). However, "The Crossword" (the large one) is only available to subscribers. Though you have one month free, after that you have to pay. Since I'm still young and in school, I have very little income and no credit card/PayPal to do this.

Are there any online crosswords that are well designed (as good looking and easy to use as the Times) and also on the level of the Times crossword covering the same themes and with the same style?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this appears to be a request for a recommendation of sources of puzzles, and is therefore outside the scope of this site as described in the help centre: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help.

Comment: I completely agree that this is not a source of recommendations.  But I use http://lovattspuzzles.com/